# Watir Webdriver - Changing proxy on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to access web from watir webdriver through proxy. Can be HTTP or SOCKS

Here is my code so far. I found sample (last 3 lines), but it gives me error:

```
irb

require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

switches = '--proxy-server=88.12.44.205:3128'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => switches
browser.goto "http://ipaddresslocation.org"
```

> Started ChromeDriver port=53928 version=18.0.1022.0
>   log=C:\Users\Raimis\chromedriver.log ArgumentError: :args must be an
>   Array of Strings
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.20.0/lib/s
>   elenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:71:in `create_capabilities'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.20.0/lib/s
>   elenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:20:in`initialize'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.20.0/lib/s
>   elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.20.0/lib/s
>   elenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in`for'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.20.0/lib/s
>   elenium/webdriver.rb:61:in `for'
>           from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.3/lib/watir
>   -webdriver/browser.rb:35:in`initialize'
>           from (irb):6:in `new'
>           from (irb):6
>           from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in`'

this line gives me error

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => switches
```

Any tips on how solve this error?

Edit:

here is the final code which worked for me:

```
irb
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ['--proxy-server=88.12.44.205:3128']
browser.goto "http://ipaddresslocation.org"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the 'switches' value needs to be an 'array of strings' rather than just a string.

The following should work:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => ['--proxy-server=88.12.44.205:3128']
```

Or if you have a lot of options to set, then you might do:

```
switches = Array.new
switches << '--proxy-server=88.12.44.205:3128'
#Add other switches values to the array
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => switches
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a SOCKS5 proxy, you can use the following switch

```
--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:PORT
```

Comment: do you know how to authorize a proxy using a similar switch? in other words, adding a user and pass argument. link to question on my page.

Answer (score 2):

As of chromedriver 2 (check $ chromedriver -v) I've managed to pass commandline arguments to chrome/chromium. For instance, to use tor as a proxy:

```
args = ['--start-maximized', '--proxy-server=socks://127.0.0.1:9050']
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :args => args
```

check other possible arguments in any chrome help documentation like

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/